# <Instance member cannot be used on type> & <Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type> - error

Tags: swift, swiftui, instance, ipad-playgrounds

I’m kinda new to Swift and when I run my code in SwiftPlaygrounds on my iPad, I get those two errors:
**ollRow** & **ollView** -> `Instance member 'ollName' cannot be used on type 'ollCase'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`
+
**ollView** -> `Cannot convert value of type 'ollCase.Type' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'` + `Argument passes to call that takes no arguments`
I initialized my data `ollCase` with a name and an image but when I try to use the data like this for example: `Text(ollCase.ollName)` I get the error and I don‘t understand what‘s wrong.
Here is the complete code:

allOLLCasesView:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ollCase : Identifiable {
    var ollName : String
    var ollImage : Image
    
    var id = UUID()
}

class allOLLCases : ObservableObject {
    @Published var OLLCases = [
         ollCase(ollName: "1", ollImage: Image("1")),
         ollCase(ollName: "2", ollImage: Image("2")),
         ollCase(ollName: "3", ollImage: Image("3")),
    ]
}
```

OLLRowView:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ollRow: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(ollCase.ollName)
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(ollCase.ollImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

OLLDetailView:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ollDetail: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
```

OLLView:

```swift
importSwiftUI

struct ollView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var data : allOLLCases

    var body: some View {
       
        NavigationSplitView {
            
            List {
                ForEach(ollCase) { Case in 
                    NavigationLink {
                        ollDetail()
                            .navigationTitle(ollCase.ollName)
                    } label: {
                        ollRow(case: Case)
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("...")
        }
    }
}
```

It would be awesome if someone could help me und explain what I did wrong and what to correct!

I have tried all kinds of defining/switching variables, but I can't seem to find the right solution…

Comment: You need to pass an instance of OLLCase to the row view, `OLLRow(case: Case)`and use that in the view. Note that properties, parameters and variables should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: I recommend you read the **very basics** of `SwiftUI`, see for example: [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/) and 
   [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app). 
  Also rename your variables to lowercase, it confuses everyone including the compiler. Once you have an understanding of these concepts, you will be in a better position to code your App and understand any answers. Note, `Image` is a `View`, you should not have it in your `OLLCase`

Comment: Thank you guys for the advice! I will be looking into the courses you suggested me @workingdogsupportUkraine